# Fill in the blanks - Word: statistic

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, vocabulary

> Fill in the blanks:
>
> In prediction markets, no individual opinions are excluded. Everyone can give an opinion. Also, since the group's decision is arrived at
>   ________ , no one is forced to change their opinion.
>
> 1. statistics ||| 2. statistic ||| 3.statistically ||| 4. statistical ||| 5.statistician

(Question from Inside Reading 4)

The answer of the book is "3. statistically". But I think it sounds odd. My instructor somehow justified the answer but he also said that maybe something is missing here. If it is the correct answer, I want to know why and if it is not, then what is the correct answer? (I think maybe "1. statistics" is the correct answer)

Comment: It doesn't sound odd. Also, it should be "group's decision".

Comment: @shin Can you explain what it means? My instructor said maybe, it needs a pause between at and statistically. what about statistics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the options given, the answer can only be *statistically* because the way the sentence is constructed needs an *adverb* to *describe* the manner in which the group's decision was reached. None of the other words based on the root word *statistic* fit the sentence.

> the group's decision is arrived at *statistically*.

Whether or not it makes *sense* is another matter. I think a better adverb in this instance would be *democratically*. This is because the sentence seems to imply that everybody in the group puts forward an  opinion, and this forms the decision that is reached. This sounds to me like the democratic process, where everybody's "vote" counts and the majority is respected. To say that something was done *statistically* means it was based on statistics, but this normally refers to data taken from a group as a sample to represent something larger. When a group makes a *decision* they are acting as a *whole*, not really as a sample or test group.

If you wanted to use the word "*statistics*" as you suggest, it could be phrased:

> the group's decision is *based on statistics*.